# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword() 400() POST Error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I’m currently implementing the new firebase auth() in my angularjs app and every time I call

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

it does return my promise and error / user object, but at the same time throws the following error in the console:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[myKey] 400 () firebase.min.js:110
```

Seems to be working as expected but I don't like errors in my console :3

EDIT: Full console error (minified unfortunately):

```
firebase.min.js:110 POST
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[myKey] 400 ()
L.send @ firebase.min.js:110
S.xe @ firebase.min.js:151
Vf @ firebase.min.js:149
(anonymous function) @ firebase.min.js:154
H @ firebase.min.js:77
$f @ firebase.min.js:154
(anonymous function) @ firebase.min.js:162
e.za @ firebase.min.js:80
Cd @ firebase.min.js:84
yd @ firebase.min.js:84
H.Nd @ firebase.min.js:83
id @ firebase.min.js:77
```

Guess I'll have to contact firebase support, right?

Comment: please attach the full network console response in your question.

Comment: I did, it's minified unfortunately...

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword will return a 400 when an error occurs like "invalid password". It is the intended behavior. When you sign in successfully, it shouldn't. Confirm that you are not getting the 400 response on successful sign in.

Comment: Thanks - that's correct!

Comment: So I'm just coming across this 400 error — I haven't found any documentation on how one should properly handle this error.  Is this just something you basically ignore (because it's intended behavior), or is there a preferred method out there for handling this sort of response when the password is invalid (so that this error isn't displayed in the console)?

Comment: This post is 1 year old now but I'm getting the same error on my app. Could be great to have a solution to this. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can confirm @bojeil's answer, the error is intended behavior. Does not happen when password is correct!

Comment: Is there a way of handling the errors in other fashion?, it's not so cool to have the error reported in the terminal with the API key and everything...

Comment: Agreed, I looked into it though and it would be hard to do anything with that key. Also the vast majority of users won't have the terminal open / won't understand the message